# VLOOKUP dynamic column Index

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Trying to do VLOOKUP from Sheet2 to Sheet1.

It's giving incorrect result. It should be 1 for W27, 2 for W28 ....18 for W44. Instead, it's giving returning 18 for each week.

[image]

```
 Sub VLookup()

Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer


 Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 
 I = 10
 
 While sh1.Cells(1, I) <> ""
 
 J = 2
 
    While sh1.Cells(1, J) <> ""
        
        
        sh1.Cells(2, I) = Application.VLookup(Range("I2"), sh2.Range("I:AA"), Application.Match(sh1.Cells(1, J), sh2.Range("I1:AA1"), 0), 0)
        
        J = 1 + J
        
        Wend
                
I = I + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: `...VLookup(Range("I2")...` should probably have the parent sheet: `...VLookup(sh1.Range("I2")...`

Comment: Also you do not need the inner loop.  Remove it and just use I as reference:  `sh1.Cells(2, I) = Application.VLookup(sh1.Range("I2"), sh2.Range("I:AA"), Application.Match(sh1.Cells(1, I), sh2.Range("I1:AA1"), 0), 0)`

Comment: Thanks! I will study it tomorrow. Too tired and thick headed to grasp it now :)